# my app don't receive a parse notifications

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I can see my push notification in my table on parse.com. But all my devices cannot receive any notifications.
Permissions from manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.james.fappsilya.fappsapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.james.fappsilya.fappsapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Receivers and services

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />



    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.james.fappsilya.fappsapp.Receiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.james.fappsilya.fappsapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

MyApplication

```
package com.james.fappsilya.fappsapp;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "my code", "my code");

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("global", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And Receiver

```
package com.james.fappsilya.fappsapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.james.fappsilya.fappsapp.Activity.MainActivity;
import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

/**
 * Created by fappsilya on 01.04.15.
 */
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Parse Push via mobile network, that solved my error as my University Wi-Fi was blocking it for some reason.